# format and trim number

Tags: php, regex, numbers

Is there a way In PHP to just get the first two digits from any given number so for instance:
get 17 from 1700, 
14 from 1457, 
13 from 130
and if digits are single or double digits leave them as they are. 
And at last is there a way to find out if the last two digits of four digit number are zeros so, for instance, distinguish 1700, 1600 etc.

Comment: `while(num >= 100) num = (int)num/10;` and similarly save the remainders for checking zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (substr($foo, -2) == 00) { // Check if last two digits are zero
    echo "double zero!";    // Do something if they are
}
if (strlen($foo) > 2) {  // Check if there are more than 2 digits
    $foo = substr($foo, 0, 2); // If so only return the first 2 digits
}
echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) To get the first two digits in php you'll want to use the substr method, as described here: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

(2) I'm not clear on what you mean by "leave them as they are" here:

> if digits are single or double digits leave them as they are.

(3) For searching for characters in a larger string I would suggest using regular expressions as described here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Please note, PCRE regular expressions are a very broad subject, so be sure you really need them. A famous quip about programmers and problems comes to mind.